# Usage of Gulp Since or 'vinyl-filter-since'

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin

I'm trying to build a simple image optimizer that only triggers on images added "since" 7 days ago. The purpuses is to run it on a webserver each weekend to optimize images added through the week.

So, far I got this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('images/**/*.{jpeg,jpg,png,gif}', {base: './'})
        .pipe(imagemin([
        imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true})
        ], {
            verbose: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

This script now runs on all images in the "images" folder. I've tried with the option "since" on gulp.src with no luck. Does anybody have any advice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show how you tried the `since` option, so we can't help you there.  The following is untested but something like this:

```
const today = Date.now();
const sevenDays = 604800000;  // in milliseconds

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('images/**/*.{jpeg,jpg,png,gif}', {base: './', since: (today - sevenDays)})
```

Get today's date, subtract 7 days (604800000 milliseconds) from it and use that as your `since:` value

Comment: Great, glad I could help.